# R scrape HTML table with multiple subheaders

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table

I'm trying to import the list of nuclear test sites (from Wikipedia's page) in a data.frame using the code below:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

theurl <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_test_sites"
webpage <- getURL(theurl)
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage)); close(tc)

pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

# Find XPath (go the webpage, right-click inspect element, find table then right-click copyXPath) 
myxpath <- "//*[@id='mw-content-text']/table[2]"

# Extract table header and contents
tablehead <- xpathSApply(pagetree, paste(myxpath,"/tr/th",sep=""), xmlValue)
results <- xpathSApply(pagetree, paste(myxpath,"/tr/td",sep=""), xmlValue)

# Convert character vector to dataframe
content <- as.data.frame(matrix(results, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE))
names(content) <- c("Testing country", "Location", "Site", "Coordinates", "Notes")
```

However there are multiple sub-headers that prevent the data.frame to be populated consistently. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [htmltab](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmltab/index.html) package. It allows you to use the subheaders for populating a new column:

```
library(htmltab)
tab <- htmltab("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_test_sites",
           which = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[4]/table[2]",
           header = 1 + "//tr/th[@style='background:#efefff;']",
           rm_nodata_cols = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this example](http://cpsievert.github.io/slides/web-scraping) by Carson Sievert that worked well for me:

```
library(rvest)
theurl <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_test_sites"
# First, grab the page source
content <- html(theurl) %>%
  # then extract the first node with class of wikitable
  html_node(".wikitable") %>% 
  # then convert the HTML table into a data frame
  html_table()
```

Comment: Looks like `readHTMLTable(getURL(theurl), which = 2)` will get you the same table as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
l.wiki.url <- getURL( url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_test_sites" )
l.wiki.par <- htmlParse( file = l.wiki.url )

l.tab.con <- xpathSApply( doc  = l.wiki.par
                        , path = "//table[@class='wikitable']//tr//td"
                        , fun  = xmlValue
                        )
```